# loading a UINavigation controller from a UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface-builder, uinavigationcontroller

i am designing an app that has a login screen. it is a UIView with username/password and a button to submit. once the user authenticated successfully, i want to load a new xib file that holds a navigation controller and a navigation bar. below the bar i want to load a tableView and switch between other views as i move along with the programming of it.

what i did is create a new class that inherits from UINavigationController and assembled the xib file to include the navigation controller. i hooked it back up to file's owner and i'm loading the navigation controller modally like this:

```
 myNavController* navVC = [[myNavController alloc] initWithNibName:@"navXibFile" bundle:nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:navVC animated:YES];
    [navVC release];
```

this works okay as the navigation controller shows up. however, it shows up with no title, even though i've set one up in IB. moreover, the tableView's delegates are hooked up via IB but i cannot even see empty lines. all i see is an empty navigation bar at the top and blank view (one piece) below it.

thank you for your help.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that you are not supposed to subclass UINavigationController.  There is actually a lot of customization you can do with UINavigationController, UINavigationItem and UINavigationControllerDelegate.

Comment: thanks simon. so for this case would you recommend subclassing UIViewController?

Comment: Indeed, UIViewController is totally meant to be subclassed, and you can do most of the customization of a UINavigationController by changing the UIViewController's UINavigationItem property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i figured it out... first it's a design decision right? is the app being managed by a navigation controller? if so (which is my case), expect the main (first) view, that is a login page, all you need to do is to hide the navigation bar in your ViewdidLoad for the main view:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

once the user logs in and you push the next view like this:

```
MainTableViewController* mainTableVC = [[MainTableViewController alloc] 
                                        initWithNibName:@"MainTableViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:mainTableVC animated:YES];
[mainTableVC release];
```

and lastly, in the ViewDidLoad of the next view controller:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

in case your app needs a navigation controller for a specific section of the app but not all if it, you will need to use the VC to manage this, in a similar way the appDelegate manages the sample navigation based sample app.

i hope this helps anyone struggling with wrapping their minds around the design patterns implemented here.

cheers.