# uiview to uinavigation? app delegate?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, xcode4

So, the app I am working on starts out with a regular view controller (Root View). Upon click of one of the buttons I want a Navigation Controller pushed. Do I need to make the Root View controller the delegate? I've already tried using MyAppsNameAppDelegate as the delegate but it didn't work or I don't know what I'm doing.

Should I start over and follow this suggestion?
[loading a UINavigation controller from a UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891051/loading-a-uinavigation-controller-from-a-uiview)

I don't want to do this programmatically either. I'm not ready for that yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To speed up your project, I suggest you to start over the project from **Navigation-based App** instead of **View-based App**. The Navigation-based App template has wired up things for you by default.